# NSNotification is called every time I tap the screen

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I my game I am sending out an NSNotification to hide the banner ad during the game and show the banner ad on the main menu and game over scenes. This works fine except for some reason every time I tap on the screen the notification to hide the ad is called and the ad disappears. Here is the code to setting up the notifications in the GameViewController:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showBanner:", name: "showAdBanner", object: nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "hideBanner:", name: "hideAdBanner", object: nil)
```

And then the two functions:

```
func showBanner(notification: NSNotification){

        self.googleBannerView.hidden = false
        var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
        self.googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)
        println("show banner")

}

func hideBanner(notification: NSNotification){

        self.googleBannerView.hidden = true
        println("hide banner")

}
```

In the main menu scene and game over scene:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showAdBanner", object: nil)
```

Then in the game scene:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("hideAdBanner", object:nil)
```

It is very strange why when ever I tap the screen on the main menu scene and game over screen the ad banner disappear. Any ideas? I really need help this is the only thing holding me back from publishing my game. Thank you in advance.

-Vinny

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `hideBanner` function. See what calls it.

Comment: Does it print `hide banner` in the console when the banner disappears?

Comment: @rmaddy When a put a break point at the top of the hideBanner function it crashes. It says: (lldb).

Comment: @der_michael No it does not.

Comment: At this point I assume that your banner doesn't hide but your scene gets drawn on top of it. You would need to reduce the scenes viewport by the size of the banner.

Comment: It's not crashing, it's stopping at your breakpoint. Look at the stack trace on the left side of Xcode's debugger. Click the "play" icon in the debugger to continue app execution.

Comment: @der_michael Yes but the problem is it doesn't switch scenes it only disappears. I toon the background off and it will disappears.

Comment: It disapears because your scene is rendered on top of it. Even if the scene is blank...

Comment: @der_michael Sorry it DOES print hide banner

Comment: Are you adding your menu scene and game over scene on top of your game scene? If so, remove the hide observer and instead hide it when your menu scene or game over scene get removed from display.

Comment: @der_michael I am doing .presentScene. Is this adding it on top?

Comment: It pretty much depends on where you call `postNotificationName`.

Answer (score 0):

When you display your banner you would need to reduce your games scene by the frame of the banner.

> In iOS, SCNView is a subclass of UIView

so just resize your SCNView so that both of the fit on the screen at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it. All I did was change the location where I post the notification. I changed it to hide when I press the play and try again buttons. Thank you so much for everyone's help!
-Vinny